# Combining ES6 Generator with Promises

Tags: ajax, generator

Let's say I am making ajax calls. And the back-end returns only 10 items at a time. I can use 'skip' parameter, to get more elements. Server also returns total number of elements. So if I want to get all existing elements, my workflow should probably look like:

- make the initial ajax call
- if totalRows greater than (previousSkip(initialy 0) + limit(constant of 10)) then

  - call again with skip = previousSkip + 10

Recursive function wouldn't work here, right? So how can I make this, using a generator?

I am hoping to get only necessary data, eg. if I call .next() 5 times it makes 5 calls, and gets 50 rows, even if there are million of total rows in database.

Comment: You could use recursion. Create a function (`getStuff`) - pass in the amount to skip - check if more rows to get, re-call `getStuff` with new skip parameter.

Comment: but that makes all possible calls immediately, whereas I need to make them one by one, next should follow only after the previous call been resolved

Comment: It doesn't make them all immediately - you wait for the response, do the row check in the response callback, and recall your function from the callback. So the flow is: Initial call with 0 skip -> Wait for response -> Response happens -> Check if more rows needed -> Re-call AJAX function.

Comment: I was hoping somehow to make use of generators, so if I call .next() 3 times it would retrieve only 30 items and wouldn't even bother making other calls. What if in total there are ten thousand rows?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with generators, so I can't really speak to that. I'm just saying you *could* do all of this with recursion.

Comment: Don't think you can accomplish what you're wanting with generators, at least not in ES6. All the generator will be able to return is the promise, not the results from the request.

Answer (score 0):

The most you can do with generators in regards to asynchronous calls with promises is for it to return the promise. Below uses jQuery ajax as an example, you can of course substitute your own promisified ajax method.

```
function genGetData* (url, start, limit) {
    while (start < start+2000) { // conditional is just a safety net
        yield $.get(url, {start: start, limit: limit});
        start += limit;
    }
}

var getData = genGetData('foo.php', 0, 10);

// get first 30 rows
$.when(getData.next().value,getData.next().value,getData.next().value)
    .then(function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        args.forEach(function (data) {
            console.log(data); // will be in order by set of results
        });
    });
```

---

Applying that to your situation a bit more, you would need to create a variable to hold the total records and pass that to your generator so that after the first request, you can update it so that the generator will know when to stop.

```
function genGetData* (url, options) {
    while (options.start < options.total) {
        yield $.get(url, {start: options.start, limit: options.limit});
        options.start += options.limit;
    }
}

var options = {
    start: 0,
    limit: 10,
    total: 1 // this just needs to be greater than start, we'll update it in a moment
}
var getData = genGetData('foo.php', options);

getData.next().value.then(function (data) {
    options.total = data.total;
    var promiseArray = [];
    for (let promise of getData) {
        promiseArr.push(promise);
    }
    $.when.apply(null, promiseArray).done(function () {
        console.log(args); // data in order in chunks of 10, excluding the first 10
    });
});
```

So, when .next() is called on the generator the first time, we access it's promise and wait for it to complete so that we can get the total. After we update the total, we then do a for of loop on the generator to get the rest of the data. This however still doesn't fix the fact that you'll be sending way too many requests in parallel.

Comment: I still don't get it, I made something similar, this works as long I use .next(). But if I try to get all available data with `for (let i in genData)` it chokes at while loop. I think this would be a lot easier if I could use RxJs's Observable, unfortunately I'm not allowed. Is it possible to emulate Observable using generators?

Comment: you could use `for (let promise of genGetData(url, start, limit, count))` if you first get a count of how many records you have so that you can force the generator to stop generating promises when it has reached the end, however, sending thousands of requests in parallel is a bad idea both for the server and the client, so you'll likely want to implement some kind of delay into it every n requests.

Comment: that's the thing I can access total from the `.then` but I have to have `for` outside of it, and then that won't work. Probably I need to try wrapping one generator into another... Darn it! I wish I could use RxJs.

Comment: that's the thing, you'll have to send one request up front to get the count, then initialize the generator and do the `for of` to get the rest.

Comment: again: I'm sending initial request, that gives me a promise, then I have to use 'then' from inside `then` I can't yield (babel won't let me to compile that code for whatever reason).

Comment: you can't yield from an asynchronous callback. about to add an example in my answer that... "solves" that issue